# App thinning with deployment target set to iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

To take advantage of the app thinning feature came along  with iOS 9, we have to use xcassets catalog in our project. However, the document also said:

> Xcode 6 provides different functionality for asset catalogs depending on the deployment target for your project:
>
> For all projects, individual images can be loaded using set names.
>
> For projects with a deployment target of at least iOS 7 or OS X 10.9, Xcode compiles your asset catalogs into a runtime binary file format that reduces the download time for your app.

If the deployment target is set to iOS 7, the assets catalog will be compiled to a .car file, while for target of iOS 6, the images will be simply copied into the app bundle.

So the question is:

- If I use assets catalog instead of bundles, but let the deployment target stay on iOS 6, and upload the app archive to iTunes connect, will the server do app slicing for devices running iOS 9?
- If I only have @2x images in the asset catalog, does the sliced app include those images for iPhone 6 plus devices?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after several tests, I got the answers.

1. App slicing will **NOT** be applied  if you set deployment target to iOS 6. All the images in Images.xcassets will simply be copied into the app bundle. So, if you want your image resources to be sliced on iOS 9, you have to set your deployment target to iOS 7 or higher.
2. Yes, it does.